# Displaying an image over multiple buttons - kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to display a single image over multiple different buttons (as shown in the picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQ99R.jpg)

When I try to do so, the image gets covered by the buttons and hidden in the background.

What I want to know is that is this even possible in kivy? If yes, where do I define the image, in the label or button?

Comment: This is both possible and very easy in Kivy, it isn't clear what part of it is giving you difficulty. Please post a minimal runnable example showing what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string("""
<Base>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        size_hint: 1, 1
        Button:
            text: "Button 1"
            on_press: print(self.text)
        Button:
            text: "Button 2"
            on_press: print(self.text)
        Button:
            text: "Button 3"
            on_press: print(self.text)
        Button:
            text: "Button 4"
            on_press: print(self.text)
    Image:
        source: 'wolf.png'
""")


class Base(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Base, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class SampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Base()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    SampleApp().run()
```

produces this:
[image]

Of course you have to provide an image yourself ;o)

Comment: Thanks so much for helping. I had was defining the image under the label. 
Also, the reason it was hidden behind the buttons was because i was defining the image before the buttons.